# PHP/MySQL blog system

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a blog system and I want to add 'tags' to my blogposts. These are similar to the tags you see here, they can be used to group posts with similar subjects.

I want to store the tags in the database as a comma-separated string of words (non-whitespaced strings). But I'm not quite sure how I would search for all posts containing tag A and tag B.

I don't like a simple solution that works with a small database where I retrieve all data and scan it with a PHP loop, because this won't work with a **large** database (hundreds if not thousands of posts). I do not intend to make this many blogposts, but I want the system to be solid and save worktime on the PHP scripts by getting right results straight from the database.

Let's say my table looks like this (it's a bit more complex actually)

```
blogposts:
id   | title         | content_html                  | tags
0    | "hello world" | "<em>hello world!</em>"       | "hello,world,tag0"
1    | "bye world"   | "<strong>bye world!</strong>" | "bye,world,tag1,tag2"
2    | "hello you"   | "hello you! :&gt;"            | "hello,tag3,you"
```

How would I be able to select all posts that contain `"hello"` as well as `"world"` in the tags? I know about the LIKE statement, where you can search for substrings, but can you use it with multiple substrings?

Comment: Don't do this.  Create a table for the tags and use that to store the tags, one per row, matched to the post ids.  Doing it this way will be slower and more difficult to maintain.

Comment: @EdCottrell Thanks for the tip, I haven't really thought of that! It makes my life so much easier :) I'll leave the question open for a few more hours if some people might have other useful suggestions

Comment: Just a good schema will do the trick btw what do you mean of `I don't like a simple solution that works with a small database where I retrieve all data and scan it with a PHP loop`?

Comment: Where I have to select all blog posts in order to find out what blog posts have what tags in PHP.. that's what the database is for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't index a field of csv values in a meaningful way, and SQL doesn't support being able to find a unique value in a field of CSV values. Instead, you'll want to set up two more tables, and make the following alteration to your table.

blogposts:

id | title | content_html

tags:

id | tag_name

taxonomy table:

id | blogpost_id | tag_id

When you add a tag to a blog post, you will insert a new record into the taxonomy table. When you query for data, you'll join across all three tables to get the information similar to this:

```
SELECT `tag_name` FROM `blogposts` INNER JOIN `blogposts_taxonomy` ON
`blogposts`.`id`=`blogposts_taxonomy`.`blogpost_id` INNER JOIN `blogpost_tags` ON
`blogposts_taxonomy`.`tag_id`=`blogpost_tags`.`id` WHERE `blogposts`.`id` = someID;
```

//UPDATE

Setting up the N:M relationship gives you a lot of options during the build out of your application. For example, say you wanted to be able to search for blogposts that were all tagged "php." You could do that as follows:

```
SELECT `id`,`html_content` FROM `blogposts` INNER JOIN `blogposts_taxonomy` ON
`blogposts`.`id`=`blogposts_taxonomy`.`blogpost_id` INNER JOIN `blogposts_tags` ON
`blogposts_taxonomy`.`tag_id`=`blogposts_tags`.`id` WHERE `blogposts_tags`.`tag_name`="php";
```

That will return all blogposts that have been tagged with the "php" tag.

Cheers

Comment: 'You can't index a field of csv values in a meaningful way' really convinced me, but why the extra taxonomy table? Having instead of tag_id's tag_name's would be equally functional right? And it saves the trouble of saving the tags separately..

Comment: By using the taxonomy table, you allow yourself to have an N:M relationship between posts and tags. That way, you can use the same tag across multiple posts, and tag one post with multiple tags. For example: Say you have blogpost 1, with two tags. The taxonomy table would have two records, one with blogpost_id=1, tag_id=1, and one with blogpost_id=1, tag_id=2. The converse would be two posts tagged with the same tag. That would create these entries: blogpost_id=1, tag_id=1 and blogpost_id=2, tag_id=1.

Comment: Hmm, it does make it easier to see what tags are available, but on the other hand I have to be careful not to have tags without posts assigned to them.. at least, that was not my intention

Comment: Ok,I can't get it to format in the comments. There's an example of using this for a search in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and ideas anyway! :) I'll see what magic I can do to make it all work

Comment: If it works out for you, accept the answer so I can beat my boss's reputation, please. ;D

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted to store the data like this the `FIND_IN_SET` mysql function would be your friend.

Have the function twice in the where clause.

But it will perform horribly - having a linked table one-to-many style as already suggested is MUCH better idea. If you have lots of the same tags a many-to-many could be used. Via a 'post2tag' table.